# Spreading props conditionally and getting a TS error regarding props missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to spread some props conditionally but I am getting an error

> Type '{ activeStyles: { [key: string]: string; }; onClick: () => void; text: string; } | { inactiveStyles: { [key: string]: string; }; onClick: () => void; text: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BtnProps'.
> Type '{ activeStyles: { [key: string]: string; }; onClick: () => void; text: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'BtnProps': bg, color

This is my component:

```js
interface BtnProps {
  bg: string
  text: string
  color: string
  onClick: () => void
}

export const Toggle: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(true)

  const MyBtn = ({ text, bg, color, onClick }: BtnProps) => {
    return <Button {...{ bg, color, onClick, size: 'sm' }}>{text}</Button>
  }

  const activeStyles: { [key: string]: string } = { color: 'white', bg: 'blue.500' }
  const inactiveStyles: { [key: string]: string } = { color: 'blue.500', bg: 'white' }

  console.log(activeStyles) // { color: 'white', bg: 'blue.500' }

  return (
    <Center d="flex">
      <MyBtn
        {
          ...{
            onClick: () => setBtnClicked(true),
            text: 'document',
            ...(btnClicked ? { ...activeStyles } : { ...inactiveStyles }),
          }
        }
      />
    </Center>
  )
}
```

To get it working I should do this which is the same I think:

```js
  <MyBtn
    {...{
      onClick: () => setBtnClicked(true),
      text: 'Document',
      ...(btnClicked ? { color: 'white', bg: 'blue.500' } : { color: 'blue.500', bg: 'white' }),
    }}
  />
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If there a reason for the spread operatorr?  Why not `...(btnClicked ? activeStyles : inactiveStyles )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend your interface from `DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,HTMLButtonElement>`
so it can have properties of default button.
the full code is

```
import React, {
    ButtonHTMLAttributes,
    DetailedHTMLProps,
    FunctionComponent,
    HTMLProps,
} from "react";

interface BtnProps extends DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,HTMLButtonElement>  {
  bg: string
  text: string
  color: string
  onClick: () => void
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <MyBtn
      onClick={() => setBtnClicked(true)}
      text="document"
      {...(btnClicked ? activeStyles : inactiveStyles)}
   />
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).